# Highlight li from Different Menus on the Same Page at the Same Time

Tags: menu, html-lists, highlight

```js
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu li a").on('click', function() {
        var page = $(this).data('page');
            $("#pages .page:not('.hide')").stop().fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).addClass('hide');
                $('#pages .page[data-page="'+page+'"]').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script>$(function () {
    $("#categories li, #bottom-page li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#categories li, #bottom-page li").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
    
<script>
    function goto($hashtag){
        document.location = "store.html#" + $hashtag;
    }
</script>
```

```css
#categories {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 86%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 43%);
    float: left;
}

#categories ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #f1c96c;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32%;
    margin-top: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
}

#categories ul li:hover {
    background-color: #f2e860
}

#categories ul li a {
    color: #112c61;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em 0;
    display: block;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

li.active [data-page='category-1'] {
    background-color: lavender;
}

li.active [data-page='category-2'] {
    background-color: lavender;
}

li.active [data-page='category-3'] {
    background-color: lavender;
}

#bottom-page {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 86%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 43%);
    float: left;
}

#bottom-page ul { float: right; }

#bottom-page ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px; height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#bottom-page ul li a {
    font-size: .85em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block;
}

#bottom-page ul li:hover { background-color: #f3efb4; }
```

```html
<section id="categories"><div id="top"></div>
    <div id="categories-line">
        <ul id="menu" class="nowrap">
            <li><a data-page="category-1" name="top" href="#">PRODUCTS <span>A&nbsp;-&nbsp;I</span></a></li>
            <li><a data-page="category-2" name="top" href="#">PRODUCTS <span>J&nbsp;-&nbsp;R</span></a></li> 
            <li><a data-page="category-3" name="top" href="#">PRODUCTS <span>S&nbsp;-&nbsp;Z</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="bottom-page">
    <ul id="menu" class="nowrap">
        <li><a data-page="category-1" onclick="goto('top')">Page<br>1</a></li>
        <li><a data-page="category-2" onclick="goto('top')">Page<br>2</a></li> 
        <li><a data-page="category-3" onclick="goto('top')">Page<br>3</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I have a menu at the top of a page under my nav which separates products on the page alphabetically. This menu is made up of three tabs spanning the width of the page that go A-I, J-R, S-Z. Under the tabs are a bunch of products listed depending on which tab is chosen.

At the bottom of the page after the last product is a menu, the same as the top menu but styled differently i.e. Page 1, Page 2, Page 3. I would like to have Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3 correspond to the proper tab at the top when clicked. So that Page 1 and the first top tab are active and highlighted when either one, top or bottom, is clicked. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a lot to read, make it as short as possible.
If your code consists of HTML or CSS, it's better to use [stack overflow's code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?_ga=2.56926690.930183975.1628395921-90647034.1626998902)
[image: icon to use stack snippets]
EXAMPLE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <section>
            <h3>Work</h3>
            <ol>
                <li>Technical Blogs</li>
                <li>Front End Projects</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```